# C# async method call

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I would have a async call to a function as following:

I'll call a method from the main method, this function should be async, how I do this?

A little example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StartDoingNothingAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    Console.Read();
}

private static async void StartDoingNothingAsync()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        //do something
    }
    Console.WriteLine("leaved");
}
```

I would first the output "test", before "leaved", how can I practice this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option would be to introduce a delay into your async method:

```
private static async void StartDoingNothingAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    // This will be called on a thread-pool thread
    Console.WriteLine("leaved");
}
```

That won't *guarantee* that `test` will be printed before `leaved`, but it seems very likely. If you actually want a guarantee, you'd have to pass something into `StartDoingNothingAsync` that you then signal *after* printing `test`... but it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve.

Note that async methods should almost *never* be `void` - basically that's only available to allow for async event handlers. Make the method return `Task` instead - that way your calling code can tell when it's completed. (Even if you don't *use* that fact in this case, it's a good habit to get into.)

Now that we have a bit more information about what you're trying to achieve, I would recommend *not* making `StartDoingNothingAsync` an async method - just use a task instead:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(DoSomething);
    Console.WriteLine("test");
    task.Wait();
    Console.Read();
}

static void DoSomething()
{
    // Code to run on a separate thread
}
```

Comment: With this I'll achieve, that the method "StartDoing..." is completely async. In this method I'll do some staff that take a long time, for example writing a big file. The code in the main function should be executed in a thread and the "StartDoing..." should be execute in another thread. I'll reduce blocking code in the main function

Comment: @MarcelHoffmann: If you actually just want to start a separate task, use `Task.Run`. Using `async` *will* use a thread-pool thread (in tihs case), but only after the first `await` which needs to schedule a continuation. Using `Task.Run` would be a lot clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the tipp with the task. Actually I've one question. What's the different between tasks and async/await and where should I use which? Thanks for an answer previously.

Comment: @MarcelHoffmann: That's a very broad question - and you're really comparing apples with oranges. Async *uses* tasks to represent the ongoing operation, but the async method returns to the same synchronization context, so there may not need to be any new threads created. (`Task.Run` will reuse existing thread-pool threads in many cases too, but the task won't generally be running on the same thread as the `Task.Run` call.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartDoingNothingAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static async void StartDoingNothingAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(async delegate()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
            {
                //do something
            }
            Console.WriteLine("leaved");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Task for that. In that case you don't need to mark your function as async:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Task(StartDoingNothing).Start();
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void StartDoingNothing()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            //do something
        }
        Console.WriteLine("leaved");
    }
```